# How to extract a part of string in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have an input file with data like below:

```
X-X-D-X-X-A 
X-D-X-A-X
D-X-X-X-X-A-X-X
```

I need the result to be only giving me

```
D-X-X-A
D-X-A
D-X-X-X-X-A
```

Please help me!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try,

```
open my $fh, "<", "file" or die $!;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
  $line =~ s/^[-X]+ | [-X]+(?=\s*$)//xg;
  print $line;
}
close $fh;
```

or from cmd line,

```
perl -pe 's/^[-X]+ | [-X]+(?=\s*$)//xg' file
```

Comment: Can you help me with a detailed code on how to use '$line =~ s/^[-X]+ | [-X]+$//xg;' A brief example would be very helpful

Comment: Its giving me the result as 

'A

A-X-X-X-X-X-X-D

A-X-X-D

D

A'

I only want to extract string having staring point as D and ending point as A or viceversa. I donot want the result to include single D's or A's.

Comment: Same issue again.. I an still getting single D's and A's along with the actual output that iam looking for.

Comment: I found where the problem lies..My file also consits of lines such as X-D-X-X and X-A-X-X-X...https://eval.in/109625

How can i ignore these singlets?

Answer (score 2):

Tested code:

```
my @a = qw[
  X-X-D-X-X-A 
  X-D-X-A-X
  D-X-X-X-X-A-X-X
];

for my $a (@a) {
  if ($a =~ /(D[-X]+A)/) {
    print $1,"\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: i assume hard-coding the pattern as in `$s` is not desired....data might be dynamic!! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if(/[^D]*(D.*A).*/)'
```

[test](http://ideone.com/dJ5sF4)

inside a script while reading a file:

```
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
  $line =~ m/[^D]*(D.*A).*/g;
  print $1;
}
```

Regex:

`[^D]*(D.*A).*`

1. `[^D]*` line may not start with D
2. `(D.*A)` Capture(round braces) the staring from D till last A in the
   line. captured part will be stored in $1
3. `.*` left over string in the line.

Comment: Hello Vinay, could you please provide a brief code for the above answer. I am quite new to programming and cannot directly implement the above answer.

Comment: How can i use this code while taking input from txt file.?